# Different collection in EVE

Tags: python, rest, eve

I have a list of bluetooth tags that send some information. I want to create a collection for each MAC(addr) of tags. How can I do it? Here's the settings I'm using and a example JSON that I'm receiving.

```
DOMAIN = {
'ble': [
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'name',
        },
    'schema': {
        'address': {
            'type': 'string'
        },
        'rssi': {
            'type': 'string'
        },
        'name': {
            'type': 'string',
            'unique': True
        },
        'tx_power': {
            'type': 'string'
        },
        'r_time': {
            'type': 'string'
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

This is a example of JSON that i'll receive:

```
[{
    "addr": "ff:ff:00:00:2a:15",
    "datetime": "2016-10-06T05:19:38.+0000",
    "name": "ITAG",
    "rssi": -61,
    "txpw": 0
}, {
    "addr": "66:55:44:33:22:10",
    "datetime": "2016-10-06T05:19:38.+0000",
    "name": "NULL",
    "rssi": -61,
    "txpw": -100
},

{
    "addr": "47:c9:df:25:34:b1",
    "datetime": "2016-10-06T05:19:38.+0000",
    "name": "NULL",
    "rssi": -94,
    "txpw": -100
}
]
```

I've tried to route with Flask but it's not creating new Collections. Here the Code:

```
from eve import Eve
import Flask

app = Eve()

@app.route('/ble', methods=['POST'])
def create_ble():
    data = request.get_json()
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    quant = len(json_data['beacon_list'])
    for i in range(0, quant-1):
        beacon = json_data[i]
        addr = json_data[i]['addr']
        beacon = json.dumps(beacon)
        mongo.db[addr].insert(beacon)

    return 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: So what have you tried doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any additional route for this. Eve supports bulk inserts. Just POST this json to /ble endpoint but be sure that keys are matches your schema keys.